# How to use FIST? (Free Image Search Tool, by Wikimedia)

Tags: search, images, wikipedia

[FIST (Free Image Search Tool)](https://tools.wmflabs.org/fist/fist.php) seems to be a powerful tool to find freely usable images to illustrate Wikipedia/etc articles. The tool is [recommended](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia_talk:Finding_images_tutorial) by Wikipedia.

Unfortunately, I most often get `0 articles found`... there must be something that I failed to understand. There is no help page nor tutorial either.

**QUESTION:** How to make at least a few results appear?

---

Example with "Thouars" ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thouars), [FIST request](https://tools.wmflabs.org/fist/fist.php?doit=1&language=en&project=wikipedia&data=Thouars&datatype=categories&params%5Bcatdepth%5D=0&params%5Brandom%5D=50&params%5Bstartat%5D=&params%5Bll_max%5D=5&params%5Bcommons_max%5D=5&params%5Bflickr_max%5D=5&params%5Binclude_flickr_id%5D=1&params%5Bpicasa_max%5D=5&params%5Bwts_max%5D=5&params%5Bgimp_max%5D=5&params%5Besp_max%5D=5&params%5Bgeograph_max%5D=5&params%5Bgeograph_max_de%5D=5&params%5Bgeograph_max_channel-islands%5D=5&params%5Bfreemages_max%5D=5&params%5Bforarticles%5D=noimage&params%5Blessthan_images%5D=3&params%5Bdefault_thumbnail_size%5D=&params%5Bjpeg%5D=1&params%5Bpng%5D=1&params%5Bgif%5D=1&params%5Bsvg%5D=1&params%5Bogg%5D=1&params%5Boutput_format%5D=out_html&params%5Bmin_width%5D=80&params%5Bmin_height%5D=80&params%5Bab_max%5D=5&sources%5Blanguagelinks%5D=1&sources%5Bcommons%5D=1&sources%5Bwikidata%5D=1&sources%5Bflickr%5D=1))

[image: FIST]

Comment: After you have run a query you get a link just below the "Do it" button, could you please add it to the question so we can see what you have tried and to make it possible to suggest changes to your query to get results?

Comment: Just tried: check only "Articles", check "All articles" and "Show images already in the article". Result should be shown in bottom of the page.

Comment: @IvanChau You could add that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@Ivan Chau](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/26981/ivan-chau) has kindly offered advice on what to select to achieve at least some results from a search based on `Thouars`:

[image: Thouars example first part]
[image: Thouars example second part]

The results I saw were:

[image: Thouars output]